# Why setTimeout performed parallel if they part of a when chain?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, timeout

As part of exploring the `then` chain I encountered two things that I can't explain.

This is the code:

```js
let x1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('10 seconds first timeout');
    resolve(1);
  }, 10000)
});
let x2 = x1.then((p1) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('10 seconds second timeout');
    console.log(p1);
    return ('2');
  }, 10000);
});
let x3 = x2.then((p2) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('10 seconds third timeout');
    console.log(p2);
    return ('3');
  }, 10000);
});

console.log(x1, x2, x3);
```

The problems are:

1. The `x2.then` callback prints immediately after the `x1.then` callback printing. But `x2.then` gets a callback with a timeout of 10 seconds, so why doesn't this wait 10 seconds before printing? Between the first and the second there is 10 seconsd as expected.
2. The `x1.then` callback returns a string `'2'`, as far I understand this value should be the value of the returned `Promise` (wrapped by `Promise`), so why when trying to print to console `console.log(p2)` it prints undefined and not the string `'2'`?

Comment: The functions you give to `x1.then` and `x2.then` aren't promises that resolve in 10 seconds, they just set a timer to print something in 10 seconds and finish immediately. Furthermore, the callbacks *given to the `.then()`* don't return anything explicitly. The `return` statement is part of the callback given to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

`x1` looks OK--you've promisified the callback so `x2` won't fire until `resolve` is called. But `x2` and `x3` don't do what you want because they don't return promises. The `return`s inside the `setTimeout` callbacks have no bearing on the mainline promise chain, they just return from the callback block into a scope that ignores the return value.

Given the general `x1` pattern, you can put the promisified timer into a function and chain `.then`s on it to move towards the desired behavior:

```js
const timeout = (cb, ms) => 
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(cb()), ms))
;

timeout(() => console.log("a"), 0)
  .then(() => timeout(() => console.log("b"), 1000))
  .then(() => timeout(() => console.log("c"), 1000))
;

console.log("this prints first always because it's synchronous");
```

As far as the main `console.log` goes, your approach won't work because you can't turn asynchronous code into synchronous code. All synchronous code has to finish running before JS can begin working on the async task queue. You have to `await`, `then` or use a callback to get the values you want, but you can refactor the above code to handle passing values through the `resolve` call by returning something in the callback and adding a parameter to the next `then` callback.

```js
const timeout = (cb, ms) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        resolve(cb());
      }
      catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    }, ms)
  )
;

timeout(() => {
    console.log("a");
    return "b";
  }, 0)
  .then(val =>
    timeout(() => {
      console.log(val);
      return "c";
    }, 1000)
  )
  .then(val =>
    timeout(() => console.log(val), 1000)
  )
  .then(() =>
    timeout(() => {
      throw Error("whoops");
    }, 1000)    
  )
  .catch(err => console.error(err.message))
;
```

As Bergi mentioned in the comments, you need to `try`/`catch` or chain the callback off the returned promise instead of passing it in to be able to handle the possibility of callback throws correctly. The above code illustrates this by calling `reject` in the promise.

Bergi also suggests that returning values from timeouts is an antipattern. You can delay execution of the next promise without a return with something like:

```js
const wait = ms => 
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
;

Promise
  .resolve()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("a");
    return wait(1000);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("b");
    return wait(1000);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("c");
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```

Either way, for this use case, `async`/`await` should be cleaner, especially if you want to pass values along the promise chain:

```js
const wait = ms => 
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
;

(async () => {
  console.log("a");
  await wait(1000);
  console.log("b");
  await wait(1000);
  console.log("c");
})();
```

Comment: Don't pass a callback. (If it throws, your program crashes). Use `timeout(1000).then(() => console.log("b"))` instead.

Comment: @Bergi, so what should he put as an argument to `resolve` function? Can you explain exactly what is the correct way to write it?

Comment: Nothing. A timeout has no useful result. At best, make the resolve value itself the argument, but don't produce it by calling a callback function.

Comment: "*you need to `try`/`catch` to be able to handle the possibility of callback throws correctly.*" - and yet, you placed the `try` block in the wrong position in your code example. Better not take any callback at all so you don't have to deal with this problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware I messed it up. Sorry about that. I didn't want to delete since you're having a conversation but I'll edit it. I'm not sure how I can clearly refactor to avoid the callback while permitting a return value to pass to the next `.then` just yet.